# TYPO3 11.4 DBAL compatibility

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

In this changelog: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/11.4/Important-94697-QuoteDatabaseIdentifiersWhenUsedInsteadOfGloballyUpfront.html?highlight=dbal
it says, that Database fields in the TCA have to be formatted to stay DBAL compatible. Do database fields in TypoScript also have to be formatted? In EXT:cms-fluid-styled-content for example, database fields in TypoScript are formatted.

Which DBMS are supported, without DBAL compatibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypoScript is not related to this change.
TypoScript options are described [here](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/) and if there will be a change it will be [announced](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Index.html) early enough to prepare related updates.
Comparing TypoScript from early versions to current versions, shows surprisingly few changes.

[These DBMS](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/platforms.html) are in general supported, concerning TYPO3 extensions it's likely that some don't work well with each DBMS of the whole choice:

- MySQL
- MariaDB
- Oracle
- Microsoft SQL Server
- PostgreSQL
- IBM DB2
- SQLite

As DBAL became fundamental part of TYPO3 there is no option to access any database without DBAL. An extension for retrieving and manipulating a DBMS without DBAL had to be created on top of the common DBAL solution, so it could serve inside an extension but not for the whole TYPO3 installation. TYPO3 specific functionality like showing records in the backend won't work without limitations or much efforts. Therefore a non-DBAL solution will always be a foreign data-source, which is nothing bad and exists in many variations but is just not providing the basic system.

The formatting of database names, table names and table fields in query parts is a requirement from DBAL and is looking like this:

```
'AND {#tt_content}.{#CType} IN (\'text\',\'textpic\',\'textmedia\') ORDER BY {#tt_content}.{#CType} ASC'
```

The snippet is taken from [this site](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/8.7.x/Important-81751-DbalCompatibleQuotingInTca.html), that explains the requirement a bit different.

It enables DBAL to do with the code whatever is required to be secure and compatible to the different DBMS' because parsing SQL-code has clearly defined parts and is no guesswork. Partially it might be restructuring or replacing parts like `join`s, also with the aspect that prepared statements are preferred and used when possible.

Comment: Thanks, but why are database fields in TypoScripts of core extensions formatted?